# C RSA key generator

Tags: c, rsa, microcontroller, private-key, key-generator

I create a program on a microntroller (which does not run any OS), and I can't find any library in C which can give me a RSA (PKCS#1) key generator (public and private).

I suppose that OpenSSH isn't an option because it's link to Linux or Unix. I found some SSH implementation, but it supports only the client side (encoding through a public key).

Does a such C lib exists (RSA (PKCS#1) key generator (public and private) + encoding, decoding)?

Comment: hm, no OS at all, or maybe tinyOS? if so, have a look here: http://discovery.csc.ncsu.edu/software/TinyECC/ . I dont know how easy it would be to strip the parts required out of that package without using the TinyOS. Interesting question btw... RSA in the hardware itself o.O. Edit: maybe MIRACL will work -> http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/implement/shamus/implement.shtml

Comment: I highly doubt that there is a library like that, that makes no use of operating system functionality and runs on a microcontroller.
A quick google search brought this up: 
https://polarssl.org/rsa-source-code
Maybe you can use or adapt that.

Comment: @Najzero yes, there's no OS at all. I use RSA to encrypt a pairing key (which is necessary to init a connection with this hardware), while connection is critic, not communication.

Comment: @NicolasVoron see my edit: ( http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/implement/shamus/implement.shtml ) '...It is primarily a tool for cryptographic system implementors. RSA public key cryptography, Diffie-Hellman Key exchange....' sounds good to me

Comment: Hmmm... Sounds good, I'll test it and go back to you ;)

Comment: @Ben your solution is at this time (nothing tested, just code review) the best solution since it provide the smaller storage memory footprint when compiled, Najero's one seems good too, but it does a lot of not-needed stuff. I've now to test them to see if it works on my hardware. If you want to add your comments as answer, I'll upvote them ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly doubt that there is a library like that, that makes no use of operating system functionality and runs on a microcontroller. A quick google search brought this up:

[polarssl.org/rsa-source-code](http://polarssl.org/rsa-source-code)

Maybe you can use or adapt that.

Comment: In fact, polarSSL is natively build to support non-OS architecture ! :) lot of processors and architectures are supported. Great, great answer Ben.

Answer (score 2):

For the embedded project without OS you can use:

1. PolarSSL (https://polarssl.org/)
2. CyaSSL (http://www.yassl.com/yaSSL/Home.html)
3. RSAEuro (github.com/mort666/RSAEuro)

Check the licenses for use this libraries in the comercial product.
Currently I am trying to use PolarSSL for generating RSA key pairs. 
I use my cuted down version of this library that support all hardware features (AES, DES, 3DES, TRNG, SHA1, MD5, HMAC) incorporated into STM32F4 MCU.